# How to use extra field from modelForms to query an object? Django

Tags: python, django, forms

I have the following form:

```
class Recipe_IngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Recipe_Ingredient
    fields = ('quantity', 'quantityUnit')

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Recipe_IngredientForm, self ).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['ingredient_form'] = forms.CharField()
```

And I'm trying to get the value of this form to search for an object, if it exists, i'll set it to be saved in my model.

```
def recipe_add_ingredient(request, pk):
 recipe = get_object_or_404(Recipe, pk=pk)
 if request.method == "POST":
     form = Recipe_IngredientForm(request.POST)
     if form.is_valid():
         recipeIngredient = form.save(commit=False)
         recipeIngredient.recipe = recipe
         aux = form.fields['ingredient_form']
         recipeIngredient.ingredient = Ingredient.objects.get(name=aux)
         recipeIngredient.save()
         return redirect('recipe_detail', pk=recipe.pk)
 else:
     form = Recipe_IngredientForm()
 return render(request, 'recipe/recipe_add_ingredient.html', {'form': form})
```

But I get an error when submitting the form: `Ingredient matching query does not exist`, but it shows that I'm getting a value that exists via GET, and if I query the exact same thing in the shell, it return my object. Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be accessing cleaned_data, not fields.

```
aux = form.cleaned_data['ingredient_form']
```

Also note, you should define that field at class level, then you don't need to define `__init__` at all.

```
class Recipe_IngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ingredient_form = forms.CharField()
    class Meta:
        model = Recipe_Ingredient
        fields = ('quantity', 'quantityUnit')
```

Comment: That was it! Perfect answer.